# C# Need to create XmlElement with prefix and without namespace

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I need to create a serialized xml element using c# like

```
<a:Root>
    <Name>Jimmy</Name>
    <ReportPeriod>200803</ReportPeriod>
</a:Root>
```

And I am not able to add prefix without namespace. I dont need namespace as this is being passed as an argument to a java service which is not able to cast it in any other form

### c# class for serializing

```
        namespace xyz
    {
    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("Root", Namespace = "abc", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Root{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }     
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReportPeriod")]
    public string ReportPeriod { get; set; }        
    }
    }
```

---

And the method used to serialize this is as follow

```
    Root arg= new Root();
    arg.Name= "Jimmy"; // Hardcoding need to be removed
    arg.ReportPeriod = "200803"; // Hardcoding need to be removed
    XmlElement x = SerializeToXmlElement(arg);

    public static XmlElement SerializeToXmlElement(object o)
   {
       XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
       //XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
       //ns.Add("m2", "advisorIWDBRetrievalWSArguments");
       using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
       {
           new XmlSerializer(o.GetType()).Serialize(writer, o);
       }

       return doc.DocumentElement;
   }
```

Thnx in advance

Comment: xml is like this  <a:SomeNode>

    <Node1>Some value</Node1>

    <Node2>Some value</Node2>

</a:SomeNode>

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: this is what I want <a:SomeNode>

    <Node1>Some value</Node1>

    <Node2>Some value</Node2>

</a:SomeNode>

Comment: You can always edit your own question. There's no need to put that into the comments section

Comment: And I am not albe to add prefix without namespace. I dont need namespace as this is being passed as an argument to a java service which is not able to cast it in any other form

Comment: You need to post some code which on how you generate the xml if you want any help. Your question not answerable in the current state.

Comment: As Serv says we need to know more about your problem. Do you not know how to use XML at all in c#? Do you not know how to serialize the XML once you have it? Is it coming out in the wrong format? Are you getting an exception when you run the code you have? In fact, what code do you have already?

Comment: If you add a fake namespece, does it work for instance : <a:SomeNode xmlns:a"urn:myNamepsapce">...

Comment: Then that's not XML - it's something that *looks* like XML but doesn't follow the rules. Why would you expect XML tools to be able to create such things?

Comment: HI Damien,     This is an argument which is expected to be an XML element and looks like this.

Comment: See [Qualified Names](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-qualnames): "The Prefix provides the namespace prefix part of the qualified name, and MUST be associated with a namespace URI reference in a namespace declaration". Since you're trying to create something where the prefix *isn't* associated with a namespace declaration, what you're trying to produce is, *by definition*, not XML.

Comment: If you "have" to produce this piece of text then a) raise a bug report with whoever thought that this was XML, and b) You'll have to do it by string-mangling.

Comment: Thnx Damien, Let me check with the java developer

Comment: The XML libraries won't allow a prefix without a namespace definition in a parent node.

Comment: Adding a namespace is helpful, as now I am able to call the service but I need to remove the namespace value or make it "" is this possible  ?

Comment: The simpliest way (but dirty) is to generate the XML, and process the result string to remove manually the xmlns attribute. Your method should return a string instead of the XmlElement.